# Equivalent lambda expression, to get a property of every object in a list

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

What is the equivalent lambda expression of this for loop in Java?
I just want to print, in a line, the names of the objects of a list.

```
for(Attribute attr : dataSet.getAttributeList()){
            System.out.print(attr.getName() + " ");
        }
```

I tried the following but without any luck, I only got the identity hash code of the stream.
`Arrays.asList(dataSet.getAttributeList().stream().map(p -> p.getName()));`

Comment: Did you override the `toString()`?

Comment: What's `Attribute` ? can you provide the class.

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(x)` you'd do `x.collect(Collectors.toList())`. If that's it, I could write it as an answer but ... meh. A case of unread documentation, I guess.

Comment: `dataSet.getAttributeList().forEach(attr -> System.out.print(attr.getName() + " "));`?

Comment: @NicholasK No I did not.

Comment: @Marco13 could you please provide a link to the relevant doc ?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html ? The first code snippet at the top shows how to create a list using a `Collector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your name attribute is a `String`, keep going with your `Stream` pipeline.  Collect the names using the built-in `Collector` that joins the values with a separator in between each element: [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> Returns a `Collector` that concatenates the input elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order.

You can remove the unnecessary `Arrays.asList`, which is incorrect anyway; it takes an array, not a stream or a string, as an argument.

```
System.out.println(
    dataSet.getAttributeList().stream()
        .map(p -> p.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
);
```

You may also choose to use a method reference instead of a lambda expression:

```
.map(Attribute::getName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have overriden the `toString` you can get the entire object using :

```
dataSet.getAttributeList().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you haven't :

```
dataSet.getAttributeList().forEach(Attribute::getName));
```

Comment: You don't need `.stream().forEach()`, it should just be `.forEach()`. `Collection` has its own `forEach()` inherited from `Iterable`.

Comment: For some reason, when I use forEach I get that println can't be resolved. How and why should I override the method and with which?

Comment: If you want the entire contents of the object you need to override the toString in your Attribute class. Can you recheck the syntax once, it worked for me.

Comment: I did, I keep getting Can't resolve method 'println(void)'. tnx for the effort anyway.